# pyspark: passing multiple dataframe fields to udf

Tags: pyspark

I am new to spark and python. Any help appreciated.

I am having a UDF and created a spark dataframe with US zipcd, latitude and Longitude

UDF:

```
import math
def distance(origin, destination):
lat1, lon1 = origin
lat2, lon2 = destination
radius = 6371 # km
dlat = math.radians(lat2-lat1)
dlon = math.radians(lon2-lon1)
a = math.sin(dlat/2) * math.sin(dlat/2) + math.cos(math.radians(lat1)) \
    * math.cos(math.radians(lat2)) * math.sin(dlon/2) * math.sin(dlon/2)
c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1-a))
d = radius * c
return d
```

sample UDF output:

```
distance((101,121),(-121,-212))
```

15447.812243421227

dataframe:

```
zip=spark.read.option("sep", ",").csv('wasb://hdiazurepoc@dsazurepoc.blob.core.windows.net/main/zip.txt')
zip1=zip.select(zip._c0,zip._c1.cast("Double"),zip._c2.cast("Double"))
```

Sample zip1 data:

```
zip1.first()
```

Row(_c0=u'00601', _c1=18.180555, _c2=-66.749961)

Now I am trying to pass the latitude and longitude from the df zip1 to the udf distance, but I am getting error like "a float is required".
I believe the udf is not getting the data from df fields, instead its reading the df column as constant value; and hence I am getting below error.

```
z=zip1.select(distance((zip1._c1,100.23),(zip1._c2,-99.21)))
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "", line 5, in distance
TypeError: a float is required

Please let me know the right way to pass the df fields to udf.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not so sure what is the data schema you have.
But the following example is the right way to use `udf` to get the answer to your example.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import math

def distance(origin, destination):
    lat1, lon1 = origin
    lat2, lon2 = destination
    radius = 6371 # km
    dlat = math.radians(lat2-lat1)
    dlon = math.radians(lon2-lon1)
    a = math.sin(dlat/2) * math.sin(dlat/2) + math.cos(math.radians(lat1)) \
    * math.cos(math.radians(lat2)) * math.sin(dlon/2) * math.sin(dlon/2)
    c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1-a))
    d = radius * c
    return d

df = spark.createDataFrame([([101, 121], [-121, -212])], ["origin", "destination"])
filter_udf = udf(distance, DoubleType())
df.withColumn("distance", filter_udf(df.origin, df.destination))

+----------+------------+------------------+
|    origin| destination|          distance|
+----------+------------+------------------+
|[101, 121]|[-121, -212]|15447.812243421227|
+----------+------------+------------------+
```

Comment: @vaira Do you have any problem with the code above? If the answer is what you want , please select it to be answer, thanks.